# What is the purpose of a Object Declaration inside a Sealed Class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In the Kotiln documentation, they give the following example for sealed classes:

```
sealed class Expr {
    class Const(val number: Double) : Expr()
    class Sum(val e1: Expr, val e2: Expr) : Expr()
    object NotANumber : Expr()
}
```

What would be the use of delcaring `NotANumber` as a object declaration (singleton?) here?  Why not just write `class NotANumber : Expr()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it doesn't contain a significant value, the single instance of it can be reused everywhere. This saves you the creation cost of this object where you need it.

Another example of this would be Kotlin's `Unit`, which is also just an `object`.

This is just one of the examples of how you can avoid creating unnecessary instances that the garbage collector then has to clean up. Another example would be how the Java `BigInteger` class has final static fields for constants like `ZERO` and `ONE`. Although these do contain state, they are immutable, so they can be just one instance each that's reused and don't have to be re-created all the time.

Comment: I see.  If `NotANumber` was marked as a class, I would need to instantiate  it every time I needed to reference it.  That makes complete sense now, thank you.